# How to get my API and a Random keygen from a third party URL into my Controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, controller, key

I build a application in CI. Here I need a API code from a third-party website/URL. I have not any idea how to receive that code into my controller.

`$user_email = "jondoe@appsapi.com.au"`

`Example - https://www.sample.com.au/api/apps/auth{$user_email}`

When I enter this Example domain into the browser it provides a API key. Like - `A9D5w9pL` How to I get that into my Controller.

Controller -

```
public function auth_with_api() {

    //https://www.sample.com.au/api/apps/auth{$user_email}
    // here I require the API key. How can I receive it here.

}
```

Comment: You could go with a [cUrl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) request, or file_get_contents() if you can

Comment: play around with ci rest client https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient Look at this tut: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by cURL. Just download the codeIgniter cURL library from here

<del>http://getsparks.org/packages/curl/show</del> **(Dead Link)**

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl **(Update Link - Git Repo)**

Put this library file in the `libraries` folder.

So now in the Controller -

```
public function auth_with_api() 
{

    $this->load->library('curl');
    $user_email = "jondoe@appsapi.com.au"

    $api_key    = $this->curl->simple_get('https://www.sample.com.au/api/apps/auth{$user_email}'); // $api_key now get the value A9D5w9pL

    // now you can use this $api_key in this controller.

}
```

**Edit (Another way) -** 
Now you can use **Guzzle**. It is a PHP HTTP client that makes it easy to send HTTP requests and trivial to integrate with web services.

Please check out the **Guzzle Documentation** - 
http://docs.guzzlephp.org

```
public function auth_with_api() 
{

    $user_email = "jondoe@appsapi.com.au"

    $client     = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $resposne   = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.sample.com.au/api/apps/auth{$user_email}');
    $api_key    = $resposne->getBody();

    // $api_key now get the value A9D5w9pL

}
```

If you have any problem. Please let me know.